# Unable to copy a database from one mongodb account to another

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mern, mongodump, mongorestore

I usually create a copy of a database in the same cluster in the same account like this:

1. **DUMP THE ORIGINAL DATABASE**

> mongodump --uri
> 'mongodb+srv://ACC_USER_NAME:ACC_USER_PASSWORD@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/ORIGINAL_DATABASE_NAME' --archive="DUMP_FILE_NAME" --forceTableScan

2. **RESTORE THE DATABASE FROM THE DUMP FILE**

> mongorestore --uri
> 'mongodb+srv://ACC_USER_NAME:ACC_USER_PASSWORD@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/ORIGINAL_DATABASE_NAME'
> --archive="DUMP_FILE_NAME" --nsFrom='ORIGINAL_DATABASE_NAME.*' --nsTo='NEW_DATABASE_NAME.*'

And that works perfectly.

Now, I created a new MongoDB atlas account, and I am trying to copy the original database into the new account.

So the first step is similar:

1. **DUMP THE ORIGINAL DATABASE**

> mongodump --uri
> 'mongodb+srv://ORIGINAL_ACC_USER_NAME:ORIGINAL_ACC_USER_PASSWORD@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/ORIGINAL_DATABASE_NAME' --archive="DUMP_FILE_NAME" --forceTableScan

2. **RESTORE THE DATABASE FROM THE DUMP FILE**

Here I could not find which params to use.
In the first example, in the second step, the URI is like this:

> mongodb+srv://ACC_USER_NAME:ACC_USER_PASSWORD@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/ORIGINAL_DATABASE_NAME

So I obviously should replace

> ACC_USER_NAME:ACC_USER_PASSWORD

with

> NEW_ACC_USER_NAME:NEW_ACC_USER_PASSWORD

But, what about the `ORIGINAL_DATABASE_NAME`, I could not find an equivalent to put there.
The rest of the params:

> --archive="DUMP_FILE_NAME" --nsFrom='ORIGINAL_DATABASE_NAME.' --nsTo='NEW_DATABASE_NAME.'

should remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1

First, you should do `mongodump`. You already did that correctly.

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@cluster.xxx.mongodb.net/<DATABASE>
```

This command will create a **BSON** file, which we will use for restoring the database in the next step.

## Step 2

Now, you can use `mongorestore` with new cluster connection string, and with **BSON** file from previous step.

```
mongorestore --uri mongodb+srv://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@new_cluster.xxx.mongodb.net <BSON_FILE_PATH>
```

**NOTE**: You don't need to specify `ORIGINAL_DATABASE_NAME` with **mongorestore**. You should only specify the base connection string of the new cluster. **BSON** file include all the necessary data for restoring the database. So, the database will be created in the new cluster and will have the same name as in the old cluster.